# Hiding UI Button After Pressed

Tags: iphone, uibutton, hide

Hey!
I am trying to hide a UIButton after it is pressed

This is my .h code:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TemplateTestViewController : UIViewController {   }

    - (IBAction)ButtonPressed;

    IBOutlet UIButton *sample; @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton
    *sample;



    @end
```

This is my .m code:

```
#import "TemplateTestViewController.h"
#import "Page.h"

@implementation TemplateTestViewController
@synthesize sample;


-(IBAction) ButtonPressed{

    if ( ([sample.selected=YES]))

{   

    sample.hidden = YES;
}
```

I get four errors and the code does not work. What am I doing wrong? I am new so some sample code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you have issue in the your .h file with **@interface** declaration. use below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TemplateTestViewController : UIViewController {
       IBOutlet UIButton *sample;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *sample;
    - (IBAction)ButtonPressed;
    @end
```

**And in your .m class**

```
-(IBAction) ButtonPressed {

    if(sample.selected == YES)
    {   
       sample.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```